# Insight traffic source detail Report. (Youube Analytics Api v.1)

Tags: youtube, google-api, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api, youtube-analytics

I have one question related to the report from YouTube Analytics. Traffic source detail report has a maximum limit of 25.
Documentation: https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/channel_reports#traffic-source-reports.
And there is no token for the next page in the response to fetch all items and not only 25.

Please help guys to get all items up to 500.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Note: This report requires you to set the max-results parameter to a integer value of 25 or less. Unlike most other reports, this report also requires you to specify a value for the sort request parameter.

Google APIs don't all allow for paging.  In this case you are max able to see 25.

There is no nextpagelink or pageid then there is now way to get additional results.